# I can't load account on IBM's qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, quantum-circuit, qiskit-runtime

I do this but it still gives an error for load account

- IBMQ.delete_account()
- IBMQ.active_account()
- IBMQ.save_account('myAPI toke ')
- IBMQ.save_account('my API toke')
- IBMQ.load_account()

**entire error**

HTTPError               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\111\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\api\session.py in request(self, method, url, bare, **kwargs)
277             response = super().request(method, final_url, headers=headers, **kwargs)
--> 278             response.raise_for_status()
279         except RequestException as ex:

C:\111\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in raise_for_status(self)
1020         if http_error_msg:
-> 1021             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
1022

HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/version

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RequestsApiError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_297760\485379158.py in 
----> 1 IBMQ.load_account()

C:\111\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqfactory.py in load_account(self)
175         # Explicitly check via a server call, to allow environment auth URLs
176         # contain IBM Quantum Experience v2 URL (but not auth) slipping through.
--> 177         version_info = self._check_api_version(credentials)
178
179         # Check the URL is a valid authentication URL.

C:\111\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqfactory.py in _check_api_version(credentials)
442         version_finder = VersionClient(credentials.base_url,
443                                        **credentials.connection_parameters())
--> 444         return version_finder.version()
445
446     def _initialize_providers(

C:\111\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\api\clients\version.py in version(self)
47                 * `api-*` (str): The versions of each individual API component
48         """
---> 49         return self.client_version_finder.version()

C:\111\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\api\rest\root.py in version(self)
100         """
101         url = self.get_url('version')
--> 102         response = self.session.get(url)
103
104         try:

C:\111\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in get(self, url, **kwargs)
598
599         kwargs.setdefault("allow_redirects", True)
--> 600         return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
601
602     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

C:\111\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\api\session.py in request(self, method, url, bare, **kwargs)
298                 self._modify_chained_exception_messages(ex)
299
--> 300             raise RequestsApiError(message, status_code) from ex
301
302         return response

**I perform this operation, but again it gives an error for load account**

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please avoid posting screenshots, rather paste the code and error message to proper environment in the question.

Comment: Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: @Junye Huang Yes of course

Comment: Which qiskit version are you using? Can you post the code (with anonymised API toke, of course)?

Comment: @Michele Amoretti I'm using version 0.39.3, I reposted the codes in the question, do you need anything else?

Comment: Why do you execute IBMQ.delete_account() and IBMQ.active_account()? The save_account() must be executed once and never more (you have to comment the statements in subsequent executions of your program). Finally, what is the instruction following IBMQ.load_account()?

Comment: @Michele Amoretti I run IBMQ.delete_account and IBMQ.active_account because it was giving an error from the beginning and I said maybe it would be better to delete and save again

Comment: and finally I executed IBMQ.load_account because I wanted to connect to IBMQ.

Comment: I suggest to update to the latest version (I have 0.41.0), then try the new approach for loading your account: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-provider

Comment: @Michele Amoretti
Ok,Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to install the latest version of qiskit and follow the documentation you can find here, about the class IBMProvider: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibm-provider

Here is an example program:

```
# This code works with qiskit 0.41.0

# Import Qiskit
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, QiskitError
from qiskit import execute
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
from qiskit_ibm_provider import least_busy

try:

    # Create a Quantum Register with 2 qubits.
    q = QuantumRegister(2)
    # Create a Classical Register with 2 bits.
    c = ClassicalRegister(2)
    # Create a Quantum Circuit
    qc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)

    vector = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

    qc.initialize(vector)
    qc.draw()
    # Add a Measure gate to see the state.
    qc.measure(q, c)

    # the following instruction must be used the very first time, then commented
    # IBMProvider.save_account(token='MY_API_TOKEN') 

    # the following instruction is the one you will use always
    provider = IBMProvider()

    # display current supported backends
    print(provider.backends(min_num_qubits=5, simulator=False, operational=True))

    small_devices = provider.backends(min_num_qubits=5, simulator=False, operational=True)
    backend = least_busy(small_devices)
    print(backend)

    #running the job
    job_exp = execute(qc, backend, shots=2048)
    result_exp = job_exp.result()

    # Show the results
    print('Counts: ', result_exp.get_counts(qc))


except QiskitError as ex:
    print('There was an error in the circuit!. Error = {}'.format(ex))
```